# Forms7 Cascading Dropdown child not populating

Tags: office-365, spservices, forms-7

I've been following the video tutorial on using `select` boxes, and creating cascading `dropdowns`. The first level populates as expected, however the second child list is not populating. Looking at the console there are no errors.

```
$("#StateSelect").Forms7LoadDDL({
    listName: "States",
    firstOptionText: "Select State",
    fieldName: "Title",
    childID: "CitySelect",
    childList: "Cities",
    childParentField: "State",
    childField: "Title",
    childOptionText: "Please Select City",
    completefunc: function() {
        alert("Parent Select Loaded");
    },
    childCompletefunc: function(){
        alert("Child Select Loaded");
    },
}); 


Title: <input type="text" id="TitleField" listFieldName='Title' class='required' >   <br/><br/>
Email: <input type="text" id="EmailField" listFieldName="email" > <br/><br/>
State: <select id="StateSelect"></select><br/><br/>
City:  <select id="CitySelect"></select><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes

```
<select id="StateSelect"  onchange="LoadCities(this.value);"></select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#StateSelect").Forms7LoadDDL ({
        listName: "States", 
        firstOptionText: "Select State",
        fieldName: "Title"
    });      
});

function LoadCities(stateID) {
    $("#CitySelect").Forms7LoadChildDDL({
        parentID: stateID,
        parentField: "State",
        listName: "Cities", 
        firstOptionText: "Select City",
        fieldName: "Title"
    });
}
```

Comment: excellent, the suggested changed worked!